# c++ if every bool in grid is true, then

Tags: c++, grid, loops

Trying to wrap my mind around this problem but my program keeps crashing (so I'm just re-doing my loop from scratch).

What i need to do: If every coordinate in my grid is set to true, do something. Otherwise, do something else until every coordinate is true.

Pseudocode:

```
Grid<bool> g(25, 25);

while (1) {
if (every coordinate is true) {break;}

//do stuff

}
```

Can you guys help me? Specifically with the "if (every coordinate is true)" formulation?

Comment: while(!(every coordinate is true)) - then depends on Grid

Comment: That will probably depend on what `Grid<T>` looks like.

Comment: glad you asked. I was just about to ask the same question, im going to sit here and wait for an answer as well.

Comment: I'd go for `std::none_of` in addition to Rob's. If your `Grid` can be iterated, that is.

Comment: `while(!g)` I would use `operator bool()` in grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
bool every_coordinate_is_true(Grid<bool> g)
{
  bool b = true;
  foreach(x from grid) b &= x;
  //here b is true iif all elements are true
  return b;
}
```

Of course it all depends on how Grid is defined...

Comment: thanks Burkhard I had been trying to use the foreach, too.  Give me a second to work this out and I'll get back to you.  Thanks

Comment: If it is a 2D grid (25 * 25) then you could also do a double for over the grid.

Comment: I'd make this a method of the Grid itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your grid supports iterators, you could use [std::all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
Grid<bool> g(25, 25);
// If every coordinate in my grid is set to true, do something
bool all_true = std::all_of(g.begin(), g.end(), [](const coordinate& c) -> bool
    { return c.is_true(); });
if(all_true)
    do_something();
else
    do_something_else();
```

Now wrap this in a loop on all_true and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with C++ but none of the code posted looks like C++. What language specifically are you using for this problem?